# How to initialize properties in scene builder programmatically

Tags: fxml, scenebuilder, populate

In  general, I am trying to figure out how pass properties to the scene builder programmatically so that they will be included in the FXML file (created by Netbeans in my case).  More specifically, I would like to set the text property of a text variable.  Two obvious, routine applications of this would be

- Program retrieves a record, displays it using scene builder, user makes changes and presses an update button, and program updates the data record with the results.
- Program receives inputs from a FXML screen, validates them, notifies user of any errors, and re-displays the data the user entered (after all, only a sadist programmer would make the user reenter everything).

I'm using the standard MVC (model, view, controller) approach, or what I like to call load and process.  Jose Pereda in an answer to " How can a textfield from fxml file be updated by setText in java file?" seems to get me half way there.  Paraphrasing Jose:

```
public class myController implements Initializable {
@FXML private TextField myVar
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    myVar.setText("This is my hard coded Text");
} 
public void setMyVar(String text) {
    // set text from another class
    System.out.println("scene builder should show: "+text);
    myVar.setText(text);
}
```

}

The first solution, the one with the hard coded text, works fine;  but obviously that doesn't solve the original problem.

I'm guessing that to make the second, generic solution work, I would have to call a method like:

```
myController.setMyVar("whatever");
```

But if this is correct, where would I place the code? If I place it in the class that loads the FXML screen, the

```
System.out.println("scene builder should show: "+text);
```

command executes properly, but the value of myVar in resulting screen is still blank.   Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot add programming logic in FXML. FXML are dumb UI files just like HTML files and everything else needs to be done in the Controller. Why can't you use the `textProperty()` of the TextField in the `initialize()` method of the controller to validate, update etc?

Comment: As far as the FXML is concerned, I did notice that if you hard code an initial value for the text field in Scene Builder, it does appear in the FXML file.  I was curious because I thought if worse comes to worse, I could manipulate the FXML file by adding a place holder and then replacing it with the actual value (I assume java has a string method like "replace in myString a target string with myValue).   That would truly be a Rube Golberg contraption; so your second suggestion sounds a lot better.
Can you be more specific and give me a code sample.
Thank you

Comment: You can check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630372/1759128 and let me know if the code snippet makes sense.

Comment: First of all I replaced TextArea with TextField in "    textArea.textProperty().bind(customProperty);"
 since a textField is involved.  And since "customProperty" isn't defined anywhere, I assume I needed to replace it with "myVar", giving
"textField.textProperty().bind(myVar);"
But the compiler objected saying: non-static method textProperty() cannot be referenced from a static context; and incompatible types: TextField cannot be converted to Observable ...
So I'm not any further along.  Also, note the second argument in my version of initialize() is a "ResourceBundle", not "Resources"